# Formal verification on ETH EVM

Tags: codebase

Can you write verifiable code for ETH? if so what's special about Tezos in this respect, does it run faster, is writing the verifiable code faster?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to formalize EVM and use this formalization for verifying smart contracts. See for example, https://github.com/runtimeverification/verified-smart-contracts.

The main difference is that verification influenced the design of Michelson. In particular the following features help a lot to reason on Michelson scripts: arbitrary-precision arithmetic, static type checking, and limiting the number of possible runtime failures.

Answer (score 0):

The Ethereum and Tezos blockchains are different ecosystems with low level programming languages and assumptions about how the smart contracts are run. Code verification is not so much about speed, but rather verifying that a piece of code does what a specification says it does. I cannot speak for the Ethereum blockchain, but the Tezos blockchain does in fact allow for verified smart contracts. Nomadic labs has a library [mi-cho-coq](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/mi-cho-coq) to help verify Michelson contracts with the Coq language.